# Difference between \\ and / when working with path directories

Tags: c++

Whenever I do any sort of file read or write, I always use the '/'
but I've seen some examples where the value of the given filepath is '\\' instead.
So what's the difference?
Am I doing it wrong or introducing bugs if I use '/'?

Comment: A backslash is the default path seperator on Windows, it accepts a forward slash as well.  It is a bit risky when you use a library that expects the default.  But in general it is almost always a bad practice to hardcode path names in source code.

Comment: / is the default separator for Unix, \ for windows. But since you use c++ I suggest you to use filesystem library for handling paths in cross platform way

Comment: ```\``` is more error prone as it has special treatment in string: escapement. So escaping it ```\\``` as in `"C:\\file.txt"` or use raw string (C++11): `R"(C:\file.txt)"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using `/` on systems that support it. In fact, on UNIX systems it's the only thing that works.

Windows supports both `/` and `\` as path separator in most situations.

Note that a platform agnostic option is available in the form of [std::filesystem::path](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path).

Answer (score 2):

The common convention used for managing paths in Windows is just reciprocal of Linux. It's formatted something like: `C:\abc\abc.txt`, although it's your own choice which method you would prefer to access/write the file or folder.

This `\\` is an escape sequence to print a common backslash to read or write the file. Note that you won't able to use a single backslash between string value since it reads next character as an escape sequence (e.g. `\n`, `\b`, etc.)

That's it.

Comment: I was wondering why I had to write three backslashes to get the '\\' to appear correctly even here in StackOverflow. +1 from me